# How to import workspace into a workspace?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have 2 xcode workspaces and I want to use both the workspace in a single project. Is there is any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Create and execute the two pod files as you are doing now, create another workspace, add the two projects and the two pods (separate them with folders). DONT ADD THE WORKSPACES, just the projects.